# Error when initializing vis.js graph with empty edge list

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

One of my special cases is a graph with only one node and no edge.

```
data = {"nodes":[{"id":"1.5bc716135c87e","label":"Only one node"}],"edges":[]};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

However I am getting

```
jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null
at Canvas._create (vis.js:52844)
at new Network (vis.js:42565)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (1:441)
at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
at process (jquery.js:3602)
```

It should be possible to create such a graph, or am I missing something?

- I created a fiddle here, but unfortunately this works :-/ http://jsfiddle.net/w7uv5rh2/1/
- My local version does throw the error above.
- As soon as I add a second node, I do not get an error anymore
- I have vis 4.21 installed via npm

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the graph creation. Please share enough code to reproduce the issue (see [mcve])

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w7uv5rh2/1/

Comment: Well, the "verifiable" bit is important, your fiddle doesn't reproduce the issue, like you have noticed yourself. You have to make it reproducible and like I said, the error has nothing to do with the graph creation. Most likely you have to share some more code (and it has to include `hasChildNodes` somewhere!)

Comment: So this is my problem. The call to `hasChildNodes` is performed inside the vis.js library. I imported the library straighforwardly using webpack, and the funny thing is my remark that as soon as there are two nodes, no error occurs anymore! I just don't know where to begin to search the difference between my setup and the fiddle.

Comment: Well, generally, there's at least 2 ways of debugging: one is to use debugger and try to analyse the stack trace and expected/actual values in it; the other may be longer but simpler: copy your local app, describe the scenario which brings the error, then start simplify-and-test procedure: remove some stuff from the app (like back-end if you have any, some network options, html elements, css or other-features-js etc), retest if the bug is still there, if it is, repeat, if it's gone, return that back. Your target in this case is to create an minimal app and then try it again in jsfiddle.